# access admin panel on new installation

Tags: magento2.3, admin-panel, xampp, local

I have just installed Magento 2.3, hosting on local server us XAMPP, i get the following message when i try to log on to admin.

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first
>   statement or after any declare call in the script in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
>   on line 2

My code in the file reads `<?php namespace` 
I have no white space before

Comment: Which is php version using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.19

Comment: Try with php version 7.1 , i have same issue.  working properly with 7.1 instead 7.2

Comment: do i need to reinstall xmapp or can i change the Php version without starting again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue come because of space in PHP start tag of controller facing same issue just removed whitespace in:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File;
```

Removing the space resolved my error

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any white space in the code

use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as FileDriver;

/**
 * Class Validator
 */
class Validator
{
    /**
     * Config path to 'Allow Symlinks' template settings
     */
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_ALLOW_SYMLINK = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';

```
/**
 * Template files map
 *
 * @var []
 */
protected $_templatesValidationResults = [];

/**
 * View filesystem
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\FileSystem
 */
protected $_filesystem;

/**
 * Allow symlinks flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isAllowSymlinks = false;

/**
 * Root directory
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $directory = null;

/**
 * Themes directory
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_themesDir;

/**
 * Application directory
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_appDir;

/**
 * Compiled templates directory
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_compiledDir;

/**
 * @var FileDriver
 */
private $fileDriver;

/**
 * Class constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigInterface
 * @param ComponentRegistrar $componentRegistrar
 * @param string|null $scope
 * @param FileDriver|null $fileDriver
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigInterface,
    ComponentRegistrar $componentRegistrar,
    $scope = null,
    ?FileDriver $fileDriver = null
) {
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_isAllowSymlinks = $scopeConfigInterface->getValue(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_ALLOW_SYMLINK, $scope);
    $this->_themesDir = $componentRegistrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::THEME);
    $this->moduleDirs = $componentRegistrar->getPaths(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE);
    $this->_compiledDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::TMP_MATERIALIZATION_DIR)
        ->getAbsolutePath();
    $this->fileDriver = $fileDriver ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FileDriver::class);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided file can be rendered.
 *
 * Available directories which are allowed to be rendered
 * (the template file should be located under these directories):
 *  - app
 *  - design
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return bool
 */
public function isValid($filename)
{
    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
    if (!isset($this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename])) {
        $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename] =
            ($this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_compiledDir)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->moduleDirs)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_themesDir)
                || $this->_isAllowSymlinks)
            && $this->getRootDirectory()->isFile($this->getRootDirectory()->getRelativePath($filename));
    }
    return $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename];
}

/**
 * Checks whether path related to the directory
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string|array $directories
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
```

s;
        }
        $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

```
/**
 * Instantiates filesystem directory
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface
 */
protected function getRootDirectory()
{
    if (null === $this->directory) {
        $this->directory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    }
    return $this->directory;
}
```

}